# Glob function output all files

Tags: php

Hi I am using this code to output image from a file called images

```
<?php
//Path to folder which contains images
$dirname = $_POST['dir'];

//Use glob function to get the files
//Note that we have used " * " inside this function. If you want to get only JPEG or PNG use
//below line and commnent $images variable currently in use
$images = glob($dirname."*");

//Display image using foreach loop
foreach($images as $image) {

//print the image to browser with anchor tag (Use if you want really :) )
echo '<p><img style="height:176px; width:221px; float:right;" src="'.$image.'" /></p>';
}
?>
```

I called it image.php and I used this form to make the user choose the directory

```
<form method="POST" action="image.php">
<input type="text" name="dir" placeholder="choose directory" />
<input type="submit" value="choose" />
</form>
```

when I run the code it output all files in the folder I have files like test.php and files as js and css and a file called images what happening is when I run it output the js and css and all .php file put it's not output the images what the error

Comment: possible duplicate of [php foreach and glob() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543136/php-foreach-and-glob-function)

Answer (score 1):

That is extremely dangerous. Anyone can type whatever folder they want and immediately see (and in the case of PHP files, execute) all files in that directory.

Note the comment in your code about "only want JPEG or PNG", well you can do this:

```
$images = glob($dirname."*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}",GLOB_BRACE);
```

This will only allow image files of those types.

You should also be aware that `glob` is NOT recursive. You have to manually recurse through directories for that.

Answer (score 0):

Or this, if you don't want to filter the extensions:

```
//Path to folder which contains images
$dirname = $_POST['dir'];

//Use glob function to get the files
//Note that we have used " * " inside this function. If you want to get only JPEG or PNG use
//below line and commnent $images variable currently in use
$images = glob($dirname."/"."*");

//Display image using foreach loop
foreach($images as $image) {

//print the image to browser with anchor tag (Use if you want really :) )
echo '<p><img style="height:176px; width:221px; float:right;" src="'.$image.'" /></p>';
}
```